# Short Sort Max, Min code. Also Error Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, sorting

```
Option Base 1

Sub Sort_Max_Min()  
Dim i, j As Integer  
Dim arrayOne As Variant  
Dim temp As Variant  


ReDim arrayOne(15)
arrayOne = Range("C2:C16")

For i = 1 To 14
    For j = 1 To 14
    If arrayOne(j) < arrayOne(j + 1) Then
        temp = arrayOne(j)
        arrayOne(j) = arrayOne(j + 1)
        arrayOne(j + 1) = temp
    End If
Next j  
Next i

Range("D2:D16") = arrayOne

End Sub
```

So I have this little code going where im trying to sort 15 values from max to min. I Have random integer values in cells C2:C16. I am getting a "Subscript out of range error" that I can't seem to pick up on but I dont think my array indexes are going out of bounds.

Also is there a better way to do this. I Don't think it is the most efficient to make i and j go from 1 to 14. Please help!

(Btw im using this in another much larger code which is why I have variants going and not just integers... I dont think that's important though. I just want to get it down but I am still new to vb regardless ; _ ;    )

Answer (score 1):

Your issue for the out of bounds is because Columns in worksheets are by default multidimensional arrays

```
Sub Sort_Max_Min()
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim arrayOne As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant
    arrayOne = Range("C2:C16")

    For i = 1 To 13
        For j = 1 To 13
        If arrayOne(j, 1) < arrayOne(j + 1, 1) Then
            temp = arrayOne(j,1)
            arrayOne(j, 1) = arrayOne(j + 1, 1)
            arrayOne(j + 1, 1) = temp
        End If
    Next j
    Next i

    Range("D2:D16") = arrayOne

End Sub
```

I ran this code and it executed in 0 seconds. Not bad but I am sure there is an easier way to sort. I am still learning and experimenting with different sorting techniques so I am by far not and expert

Answer (score 0):

You are out of range when `j = 14`, because you have `j+1 = 15`, which is out of range.

And yes, there is a better way to do it ;)
Keep the hard work.